# DirectoryIndex not being respected on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, apache-2.2

Hey guys I'm having a really weird issue here with my AWS EC2 instance. I have set up my LAMP stack with PHP5.5 MariaDB and Apache2, I have created/enabled my conf file (below)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    SetEnv  APPLICATION_ENV live

    <Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

        Order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite>
        RewriteEngine On
    </IfModule>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

and have even tried dropping an htaccess with a DirectoryIndex in my webroot. None of this though seems to be respecting my DirectoryIndex? Any ideas? mod_dir is enabled, as well as mod_rewrite, you think between the two Apache would be able to figure it out??

You can use `http://54.200.197.102/` to check it out, security groups are set to allow on 80, and you can see my directory structure here for var dub

```
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   4566 Jan 30 18:58 backup
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu     50 Jan 30 19:10 .htaccess
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu     12 Jan 30 19:09 index.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu      4 Jan 30 18:51 index.php
```

contents of htaccess are below

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

I'm seriously at a loss atm?

Comment: That's weird I'm getting the default apache2 `It Works!` even after flushing my cache etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says: "Works: index.php".

Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: I did, very weird... Accepted. Works in Chrome, FF is being a bugger, maybe its holding onto its cache even after a hard flush..?

Comment: Did you omit some important detail from your question?

Comment: I didn't, but I believe you're correct about the caching, I think FF won't release its cache for whatever reason. +1 and waiting to accept.

Comment: Try quitting and restarting it. The last couple of releases of FF have been a little buggy.

Comment: That's what I did followed by a ctrl+f after a hard flush, seems to have resolved.... silly FF...

Comment: Remember DirectoryIndex is first match, and you overrode in your htaccess - see my answer for more explanation, it might be better to clean up your config to make it more obvious

Answer (score 0):

Apache will resolve through the DirectoryIndex config variable until it finds a match, it stops processing on the first match it finds in the directory you are browsing to (in your case the document root: /var/www)

in your config you specified the order index.html index.php, this means as soon as it sees index.html in the directory it will serve it, if not it will look for index.php and serve it if it finds it

if it doesn't find either document, then it will default to your Directory Indexes permission for the directory or the closest match which in your case is an allow so it would show directory contents

you have overridden the VHOST DirectoryIndex config in your .htaccess (which is not unusual) so that it searches for index.php then index.html - which is the behaviour you are currently seeing as index.php is the first match (even though both files exist)

basically pick your preferred file and rename the other to something else or delete it and/or reconfigure your VHOST/.htaccess file so specify the exact one you prefer (guessing index.php)